# How to store a symmetric cryptographic key in the macOS keychain?

Tags: swift, macos, keychain

I'm trying to store a 512-bit key into the macOS keychain. However, when I run the SecItemAdd function, I get a return value of `-25303 errSecNoSuchAttr`. How can I best solve this?

So far, I've tried removing the `kSecAttrKeyType`, `kSecAttrKeyClass`, and `kSecAttrKeySizeInBits` attributes. These solve the error with SecItemAdd, but break the stored keychain item (it cannot be looked up/removed).

This is the code I've got so far (based on [this example](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/swift/Encryption/ViewController.swift#L110)):

```
var newKeyData = Data(count: 64)
_ = newKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { SecRandomCopyBytes(nil, 64, $0) }

let keyTag = "com.example.accessKey".data(using: .utf8)!
let keyQuery: [CFString: Any] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeAES, // Removal leads to broken item
    kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric, // Removal leads to broken
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: keyTag,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 512, // Removal leads to broken item
    kSecValueData: newKeyData
]

let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, nil) // Returns -25303
```

I would expect this query to work fine, since all keys I used are listed in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecclasskey). Any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried adding a variable as such: ```let item: CFTypeRef?``` and then doing ```let status = SecItemAdd(addQuery as CFDictionary, &item)```. Basically what I am asking is if you have tried saving the results to a CFTypeRef array.

Comment: After some testing, Xcode told me this ```'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead```. What you are using to create the key data is now deprecated so maybe you should generate your symmetric key using something like ```let symmetricKey = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)```. Let me know if this works and I'll put it in as the answer.